# Segue to home view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to segue back to a home screen and pop everything from the stack (of views?)
I am using `UINavigationController`:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Where shall I call this method? I have tried in `-(void) prepareForSegue` which does not work. 
Basically I want to make sure when I go back to home screen there is no back button on the left of the title.  
Home screen here refers to the welcome screen of my App.

I am not sure which part of my code shall be posted. Please comment if you need to see my code.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Popping controllers isn't related to a segue (normally, at least).  You probably want to put that code wherever a user action or some program logic makes you want to go to the welcome screen.

Comment: what is your deployment target version. because - Storyboards in iOS 5 don't provide a "no-code" way to return from a segue

Comment: popviewcontroller only works if you are pushed.

Comment: If you're trying to go back to the root view controller, you can either use an unwind segue or popToRootViewController. If you're using an unwind, it probably should be connected to a button or other UI element to trigger the segue -- you don't call anything in code. There won't be any back button if you go back to the root view controller -- it doesn't matter how you get there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a Storyboard, and a UIButton declared over there is the one that triggers that action you wanna perform, you should declare an IBAction: `-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;` in the .h and implement it in the .m. Inside that method should appear that `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` code. Also remember to attach that action to that UIButton when touch up inside in the storyboard.

Hope it helped!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. To better phrase my question, it is the same as segueing without a back button. How shall I do that?

Comment: I still don't understand at all what you want to do. When you pop to rootViewController there's no back button.. Why? Because you're poping to the root view..There's no back View. Do you want a UIButton to perform that `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` action or where do you want that happen?

Comment: It's like go back to main menu when you finish one task. If I segue into the main menu from the endof the task, there is a back button on the left of the title bar right? I do not want that button so that it looks like the app just launched.

Comment: Ok, so just put that `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` code the line after finishing that task you're talking about. The popToRootViewController will should do what you want just only if you're handling the navigation controller(s) correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion is around the concepts of what a segue is and how it relates to the navigation controller stack. The stack is exactly the same as the basic data structure stack (http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) in that it's a last-in-first-out store. When you segue, you're normally adding to that stack, e.g. Pushing a new VC onto the stack. A back button in most cases would not be doing that. It would be popping, or removing from the stack. Which is why you probably wouldn't call pop methods from the prepareForSegue method. Instead try calling it at some other point, like when they tap the back button, or after some action has taken place.